# The fundamental group of the configuration space of the closed half plane.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I want to know what's the fundamental group of the configuration space of closed half plane.
closed half plane:
$$
H_{2}\equiv\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x_2\ge0\}.
$$
Then I want to consider the fundamental group of its unordered configuration space:
$$
\pi_1(\text{UConf}_{n}(H_2))
$$
How can i get it?

Is this untrivial problem? Because I wanted to treat the closed half plane as the upper half plane with its boundary the real axis but found a paper [Configuration Spaces of Manifolds with Boundary](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.00716). Although i cannot understand it, it seems to me that this paper tells this is not a trivial problem.

Comment: The configurations in a manifold with boundary are homotopy equivalent to the configurations in the interior via pushing along a collar. As such, you are asking about configurations in the plane, which a lot is known about (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3976648/what-is-the-rational-homology-of-the-unordered-configuration-space-of-points-in) for instance). The fundamental group is given by the braid group $B_n$.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Could you give me some reference about "The configurations in a manifold with boundary are homotopy equivalent to the configurations in the interior via pushing along a collar".  Much thanks. I just wonder if that so why those people discussed the configuration space by dividing the problem to the closed case and with boundary case.

Comment: That paper is written in order to set up theory of cobordism / handle attachments for configuration spaces which requires paying special attention to configurations with a point in the boundary.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Oh! thanks. Sorry for misunderstanding the paper.  Could you please give me some references so i could have a better understanding about this whole process.

Comment: I would highly recommend Sinha's article on ordered configurations in the plane https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610236 . I'm not an expert about the unordered configurations, but if you look at things related to braid groups you will find information.